# Using a generator class to generate objects

Tags: c++, class

I have few classes:

```
class Item;
class Component;
class BrokenItem;
```

I need to be able to generate `Item`s of different configurations from different combinations of `Component`s

Here's what I have done:

```
class ItemGenerator
{
public:
    ItemGenerator(const std::vector<Component>& components_);
    ItemGenerator(const BrokenItem& brokenItem_);
    // and a few more ways to generate

    const std::vector<Item>& getGeneratedItems() const;

private:
    // vector to store generated objects
    // a vector is used because multiple combination of
    // configuration can be generated
    std::vector<Item> generatedItems_;
}
```

I intend to use it this way:

```
std::vector<Component> comps { 1000, 1020, 1040, 1080 };
ItemGenerator ig(comps);
std::vector<Item> vi = ig.getGeneratedItems();
for (auto i : vi)
    std::cout << "generated item: " << i << std::endl;
```

**Question:** Am I doing it the wrong way? If so, what's a better approach? If not, what can I do to make it better?

Comment: Does it need to be a class?  If you are not storing state this could just be stand alone functions in a namespace.

Comment: @DanDan I thought I could group similar functions together. Is it bad?

Comment: @Xan A more natural expression of "similar functions" in C++ is just to use a namespace and not force a class hierarchy that is not useful (as would be necessary in Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group similar functions using a namespace:

```
namespace ItemGenerator
{
    std::vector<Item> FromComponents(const std::vector<Component>& components);
    Item FromBrokenItem(const BrokenItem& brokenItem);
}
```